# Collecting element in table after invoke the click, using c# in webBrowser

Tags: c#, click, element, invoke

How I collecting element in table after invoke the click event using C# in webBrowser.

My syntax command for invoke the click is:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("addressSearchButton").InvokeMember("Click");
```

They put the result in table with ID : address-details

Here the fragmented of HTML, Before Search clicked:

```
<div id="search-result-outer" style="width: 100%">
<div id="search-result">
</div>
```

and after search clicked :

```
<div id="search-result-outer" style="width: 100%">

<div id="search-result">
        <div id="search-header">
            <h2>Search results</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="manage-addresses">
                <div id="address-details_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">
                    <div class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix">...</div>
                    <table id="address-details" class="address-details dataTable" aria-describedby="address-details_info">...</table>
                    <div class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix">...</div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The question is : How to wait until the result come-out, and start collecting the result element?

I can't get result directly after invoke the click, because the table not come-out yet.

I tried to wait using ReadyState.Complete, but not hope.

```
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

I also tried to checking result element using loop, but it make the webBrowser stuck.

```
while (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("address-details") == null)
{ 
Application.DoEvents(); 
}
```

Comment: You could throttle the second approach with window.setInterval()

Comment: It's work... thank you...

Comment: I will post it as an answer, please feel free to accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The UI Thread might be overwhelmed by the amount of calls to

```
 Application.DoEvents();
```

as they happen in a while loop and there is no time to put the new element in the DOM as the thread is busy with `DoEvent()`.
You can throttle (slow down) the calls by using either

```
 window.setInterval()
```

or

```
 window.setTimeout()
```

You would do your check in the callback function and give an amount of time which can be quite small, but not 0.

Once the thread gets out of the callback, it has time to do different things like taking care of the dom again.

With window.setTimeout() you can do the check and schedule the next callback right from the previous one.

Another possibility might be to use

```
 Thread.Sleep()
```

but this might lead to unwanted side effects.

The cleanest and most modern solution would be to use the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which has gained more support by browsers.

If you don't mind using frameworks, I suggest jQuery, which has functions for exactly what you need and uses the Mutation Observer API if available and some polyfill for browser downloaders like IE ;-)